# IIS7 Programmatically get App Pool version in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have a diagnostic web page and I need to ensure that the website was installed on the right App Pool version programmatically in ASP.NET.

I am running IIS 7.5 Under Windows 7 but the code also have to work under Windows Server 2008 R2.

I know how to get App Pool name with those two ways:

```
 // First way to do it
 string name = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_POOL_ID", System.EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

 // Second way to do it
 string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["APP_POOL_ID"];
```

However, from there, I don't know how to get the App Pool version. I've looked at a lot of webpages and forums but I can't quite find the answer.
Anyone can help?

Comment: **full** ***diagnostic web page*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing it from the runtime how about just returning the .NET version, or System.dll? If you want to report the version of .NET that is probably a pretty accurate.

Something like:

```
Version version = Environment.Version
```

Comment: This may sound newbie, but if a client accidentally choose an ASP.NET v2.0 Application pool when installing my website, but my website project and web.config both have .net Framework 4.5 in it, will I get 2.0 or 4.5 as Environment.Version? I need to be able to tell the client he chose the wrong Pool application version.

Answer (score 0):

The following article shows how to use the ServerManager class to create an application pool and set its properties, including the ManagedRuntimeVersion:

[Adding an Application Pool to IIS7 programmatically](http://martinnormark.com/adding-an-application-pool-to-iis7-programmatically/)